# charAt(0) String index out of range: 0

Tags: java

I'm trying to get user input on their gender, and convert it to a char and uppercase.

However, I keep getting this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source) at InfoDisplay.main(InfoDisplay.java:12)`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class InfoDisplay {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        String gender;
        char genderChar;
    
        System.out.print("Enter gender (Male/Female): ");
        gender = sc.nextLine();
        gender = gender.toUpperCase();
        genderChar = gender.charAt(0);
    

        System.out.println("Your gender is " + genderChar);
    }
}
```

Comment: That happens if the string is empty. Don’t know how you manage to read an empty line from the keyboard.

Comment: try to check gender.isEmpty()

Comment: So how can I convert the user's input into an uppercase character?

Comment: There is no user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class InfoDisplay {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String gender;
        char genderChar;

        System.out.print("Enter gender (Male/Female): ");
        gender = sc.next(); //It will not take Enter as an input
        gender = gender.toUpperCase();
        genderChar = gender.charAt(0);


        System.out.println("Your gender is " + genderChar);
    }
}
```

If you are using `sc.nextLine()` to take String as an input, It will consider `Enter` as input of String when you are pressing it after entering input so you can use another alternate of `sc.nextLine()`. You can use `sc.next()` If your input string doesn't contain space so it will work here.

Answer (score 1):

That exception occurs when you do not enter any char into the console (your String is empty). I recommend to write your code with a `try/catch` block.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InfoDisplay {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String gender;
        char genderChar;

        System.out.print("Enter gender (Male/Female): ");

        try {
            gender = sc.nextLine();
            gender = gender.toUpperCase();
            genderChar = gender.charAt(0);
            System.out.println("Your gender is " + genderChar);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No gender has been entered. Please, try again");
        }
    }
}
```

Possible outputs:

- You not enter any char:

  > Enter gender (Male/Female):
  >   No gender has been entered. Please, try again
- You enter `'F'` char:

  > Enter gender (Male/Female): f
  >   Your gender is F
- You enter any char:

  > Enter gender (Male/Female): x
  >   Your gender is X

Maybe you would want to create a pattern or something like that to allow only 'F' and 'M' to be the *correct* characters.